# Вызов методов objective-c из javascript используя JSCore

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Пытаюсь вызвать метод обжектив-с из UIWebView при помощи JavaScriptCore. Не работает. Вывожу `window.objc` - все нормально. Вот упрощенный пример того, что я делаю:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"></html>" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    JSContext *context = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    context[@"objc"] = self;
    NSString *javaScript = @"function test() {  \
                         window.objc.callObjc();\
                         }";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test();"];
}

- (void)callObjc
{
    NSLog(@"вызывается");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, чтобы разрешить вызов методов objc из JS надо создать протокол, насоледованный от JSExport и объявить в нем все методы, которые должны быть доступны из JSContext.

```
@protocol JSBridge <JSExport>
    - (void)callObjc;
@end
```

И убедиться, что протокол объявлен во вью контроллере.

Ответ нашелся [здесь](http://hayageek.com/execute-javascript-in-ios/).