# Как проверить, что WebView в данное время выполняет JS-код?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, mac, cocoa

Речь идет о Cocoa-компоненте WebView. К примеру у него вызывается JS-функция:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"foo"];
```

Мне нужно как-то подождать пока эта функция выполнится и начать делать другую работу. Как это можно сделать на Objective-C? Мне нужно что-то вроде:

```
[webView waitUntilJavaScriptCodeIsCompleted];
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать - невозможно. Что можно сделать: когда джава скрипт код закончил выполнение, он может об этом оповестить objective-c код. два варианта: начать загружать новую страницу и перехватить это в делегате `- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, либо прямо из джава скрипта через JSCore выполнить метод objC, примерно как в этом ворпосе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451976/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-objective-c-%D0%B8%D0%B7-javascript-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-jscore